Probability of a Linearly Independent Subset in Random GF(2) Equations
Assume that, over $GF(2)$, an algorithm takes $k$ variables as input and generates $6$ linear equations. Each of these $6$ linear equations consists of up to $2^k-1$ terms (excluding the constant term). Naturally, since the $6$ linear equations are generated randomly, some equations may overlap.
Now, what is the probability that there exists at least one subset of $3$ equations among the $6$ that are linearly independent?
My initial approach was as follows:
The probability that $3$ equations are linearly independent is given by:
$\Pi_{i=0}^{2}\frac{2^{2^k-1}-2^i}{2^{2^k-1}}=\Pi_{i=0}^{2}(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k-1-i}})$.
Therefore, the probability that the $3$ equations are not linearly independent is given by:
$1-\Pi_{i=0}^{2}(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k-1-i}})$.
Also, the number of ways to select $3$ equations from $6$ is $6\choose 3$, so the probability that all such subsets are not linearly independent is:
$(1-\Pi_{i=0}^{2}(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k-1-i}}))^{6\choose 3}$.
The final probability that there exists at least one subset of 3 equations among the 6 that is linearly independent is given by:
$1-(1-\Pi_{i=0}^{2}(1-\frac{1}{2^{2^k-1-i}}))^{6\choose 3}$.
However, it seems that the above calculation implicitly assumes that all 20 attempts (from $6\choose 3$=20) are independent. To account for dependencies, I believe we could use the inclusion-exclusion principle. However, I am unsure how to apply it, as it’s unclear whether the initial 6 equations are independent or dependent.
How can I calculate the exact probability?
